# Compiling FFmpeg without ALMOST everything

Tags: android, linux, gcc, ffmpeg, compiler-errors

In my case I wanted to compile ffmpeg for android using the ffmpeg-android git repo. To understand my problem you should know the basics of building ffmpeg.
I only work with audio files but this question may give you points to start at in other cases of problems.
 I modified the `./configure` command of FFmpeg to avoid gpl usage and with (**important**) `--disable-everything`.

This disables everything. I needed to overlay two audio files.

**But I had some problems.**

And because I had to search several days for finding many solutions I had to combine, I started this Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I added to ./configure:

`--enable-filter=amix, aresample` .

**Rule 1**

You should inform yourself about the most neccessary filters. In my case I  needed `aresample` as well for writing the output file.

**Rule2**

Be sure what formats you want to use.
In my case I wanted to process and/or output mp3 and aac files.
Inform yourself by searching the internet for your wishes.
Good search terms: `ffmpeg {aac, mp3, etc.} encoder`
`.||. decoder`
`.||. muxer`
`.||. demuxer`

For aac I needed `--enable-muxer=adts` and `--enable-dexmuxer=adts,aac` and `--enable-bsf=adtstoasc`

**Rule3**

Enable the protocols (uri schemes) of your given input files. If you want to use inputs from /media/audios/myAudio.mp3 you have to add the file protocol: `--enable-protocol=file`

**Rule 4**

Addititional libraries:
For mp3 files use `--enable-libmp3lame`
Search the internet for more information.

**Rule 5**

If you want to combine a low quality audio file with a good quality audio file the output may become as bad as the low quality audio file. You should specify the bitrate when using ffmpeg. Search the internet for more information.

**Rule 6**

Search the internet. You may not fint the solution within seconds but if you do not stop you may find the solution. Inspect the compilation console output as well and check if every decoder and encoder you wanted is really there. FFmpeg gives this information. Maybe you used a wrong name for a file format which has a different name than the encoder. Or the encoder has another name than the decoder.

**Rule 7**
You can get a list of all supported encoders and decoders and muxers and so on by calling

`./configure --list-{what you want to list in plural}`

Example: `./confige --list-demuxers`